# How do I change the order of these fields in Upload a new document shown below?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, excel, word

How do I change the order of these fields in Upload a new document shown below?
And in a required field below that calls from a lookup ( status ) is there a way to default it to say "Select" instead of blank?

[image]

Comment: Are these the columns in doc library ?

Comment: Yes Sir they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these fields are from a content type, Navigate to your document library settings -> Select the content type -> Select "Column Order". Here you can change the order of your columns.